A question about the proof of Levy's continuity theorem
I'm reading the proof of Levy's continuity theorem by Christian Döbler but there is  one part I don't understand. Namely, in the proof of Theorem 1.1, it is assumed that $(X_n), X, Z$ are independent random variables on the same probability space and $Z \sim N(0,1)$. My problem is the following:

In the statement of Levy's continuity theorem, it is neither assumed that $X_n$ and $X$ are independent random variables nor is it assumed that $X_n$ and $N(0,1)$ are independent random variables.

The independence of the random variables is actually needed to use Lemma 2.1 because only then can we be sure that the probability law of the sum of random variables is given by convolution of the probability laws.

Lévy's continuity theorem is about convergence in distribution (weak convergence of probability measures), so there is no loss of generality in assuming independence (as long as the random variables have the prescribed probability distributions).

@nejimban Could you elaborate more why there is no loss of generality?

If you have random variables $X,X_1,X_2,\ldots$ on some probability space, you can always construct another probability space with mutually independent random variables $X',X'_1,X'_2,\ldots$, where $X'_n$ has the same law as $X_n$ and $X'$ has the same law as $X$.

@nejimban Could you tell me how or provide a reference?

Just construct the random variables separately and then take the product of probability spaces. I think any good reference book introduces independence that way.

@nejimban If you add an answer, I'll accept it.
